# scala: playframework controller action execution sequence with future

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I am having problem with my play-framework API server. I need to have some processing running in the background that is returning a `Future` with the result and then write the result as response. However, the request thread goes all out and return before my Future completes. Here is the code...

```
 def requestAction(): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
    var fResult: Future[String] = Future { "initial value" }
    try {
       fResult = doSomethingAsyncAndGetResponseString(); // return "great, everything is done"
    }
    catch {
       case t: Throwable {
           fResult = Future { "failed" }
       }
    }
    // done, return response, but the problem is, this is executed first because doSomethingAsyncAndGetResponseString() is still executing and returns later
    fResult.map( res => {
        // problem here, because I get "initial value" which is not what I want
        Ok(res)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get "great, everything is done" or "failed" without `Async.await` ? I have been using this format all over in my API server, but today it broke because in a new API that I write, the `doSomethingAsyncAndGetResponseString` is a bit longer. I didn't expect that, so something must be wrong with how I understand the structure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to write `Java` like code using `Scala`.

You are doing it wrong. Read about `Future`s and How to use them.

Here is the [tutorial](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html)

`Future`s can be composed using `map` and `flatMap` constructs. `recover` and `recoverWith` will give the user access to exception happened in the computation pipeline

You have to do something like this, given below

```
def requestAction(): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
    Future { "initial value" }.flatMap { _ =>
      doSomethingAsyncAndGetResponseString() // returns Future
    }.map { res =>
      Ok(res)
    }.recover { case th =>
      Ok(th.getMessage)
    }
}
```

#### Handling exceptions and recovering from exceptions

Exception handling is inbuilt into `Future`.

`recover` gives access to exception and also helps the user to provide the alternative success value in case of exception.

`recoverWith` gives access to an exception and also helps the user to provide/chain alternative `Future` computation which can succeed or fail.

```
Future {
 throw new Exception("foo exception")
}.recover {
  case th => println(s"msg: ${th.getMessage}")
}
```

Comment: thanks! That's an interesting read! But a quick question about your example, if I wrap it that way, then I can't `catch` any error that might arise and deal with it "properly"? the printing "failed" case?

Comment: @Zennichimaro  `recover` and `recoverWith` will help catch exceptions

Comment: @Zennichimaro added more info about exception recovery